# JavaScript: reading $_POST & $_FILES variables after AJAX submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm submitting a form through AJAX for the express purpose of displaying a pre-selected image. Selecting an image from the local drive will trigger the "onchange" event for the file-type input, and in turn call the AJAX routine. It works fine, and upon a successful "move_uploaded_file", the PHP handler returns the validated file name. The following illustrates how the AJAX submission was effected:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xForm = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("form"));
xhr.open("POST", "handler.php", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("imgDiv").src = xhr.responseText;
  }
} 
xhr.send(xForm);
```

Instead of getting the handler to return the file name, is there any way to access the $_POST and $_FILES variables after returning from an AJAX submission? This is usually possible when returning from a normal form post, using:

```
<?php echo $_POST['stringInput'];?>
<?php echo $_FILES['imageInput']['fileName'];?>
```

but I'm not able to get anything in this case.

Thanking you,

Sofia

**EDIT:** *in case it may be relevant, the handler is not in the same HTML script, but in a separate PHP file. Thanks again!*

Answer (score 0):

Because you made a mistake in code typing here:-

**Old code**

```
x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("imgDiv").src = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

**New code**

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("imgDiv").src = xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```

Means replace x.onreadystatechange with xhr.onreadystatechange

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that was just a forum post typo; like I said earlier, the code works well with no errors. My only problem is not being able to access the $_POST and $_FILES variables after the PHP handler has made changes to it, upon coming back from the AJAX submission.